# PHP: include блокирует читаемый файл, или нет?

Tags: php

Допустим, я пытаюсь писать в шаблон информацию через fwrite() в тот момент, когда другой скрипт PHP его читает и выполняет include'ом.

- Возможно ли изменить файл, читаемый в данный момент include'ом?
- Возможно ли прочитать includ'ом файл, изменяемый в данный момент другим процессом PHP?
- Как в целом происходит работа include'а: лочится ли он через flock() или как-то иначе?
- Если файл лочится (в процессе изменения), то встанут ли другие потребители в очередь, по аналогии с flock(), или будет выброшена ошибка? Особенно в случае необходимости перезаписи.

Comment: А зачем делать flock при чтении? Для полного ответа вам нужно смотреть в исходники PHP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208314/does-php-include-lock-a-file

Comment: Хороший ответ. Но мне не совсем понятно, что происходит в том случае, если я не читать буду из файла несколькими потоками, а одним скриптом писать в то время, когда другим - читать.